# when do i need more than one Fargate profile in EKS?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, aws-fargate

I am using EKS Fargate and created a fargate profile based on this doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/fargate-profile.html.

In the doc it says Fargate is used to allocate what pods are deployed to Fargate instead of Nodegroup or EC2. So my question is should I always have one Fargate profile in one cluster? Is there any reason to have more than 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider that today Fargate profiles are immutable and they do not support wild-cards. So practically you end up using more than a Fargate profile when you have a rather dynamic environment and you want to selectively include/exclude namespaces / pod tags etc. There are other reasons why you *may* want to use different Fargate profiles for different namespaces in that the Fargate profile determines the network(s) your pods get deployed to and the execution IAM role of your pod (which you *could* use to selectively determine wich ECR private repo the pod can pull from). This role is not to be confused with the [IAM roles for SA](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/iam-roles-for-service-accounts.html).

Answer (score 2):

As of Aug 17th 2022, EKS now supports wildcards in Fargate Profile selectors. This means you can now run workloads from various Kubernetes namespaces with a single Fargate Profile.  Previously, you would have had to specify every namespace, and were limited to just 5 namespace selectors or label pairs.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/08/wildcard-support-amazon-eks-fargate-profile-selectors/

For example, now you can use selectors like `*-staging` to match namespaces ending in `-staging`. You can also use `?` to match single characters. `app?` would match `appA` and `appB`.

```
eksctl create fargateprofile \
    --cluster my-cluster \
    --name my-fargate-profile \
    --namespace *-staging
```